# ArrayFormula column disappears when sorting in a filter view in Google Sheets

Tags: sorting, filter, google-sheets, array-formulas

I'd like to use `ArrayFormula` to populate a column in spreadsheet, but when I `Sort A->Z` in a filter view, the `ArrayFormula` column vanishes. In some cases, the column includes a `#REF!` error about the range, and in some cases the column is just blank after the `Sort`. The following is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do (in my actual application, I'm doing a `Vlookup` to another sheet):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XbqqedOjuSKuE-ZLIHNw59-r01EsNMpx7YVqOoxSOR4/edit?usp=sharing
[image: arrayformula use]
[image: bad filter view]

The `column 3` header uses an `ArrayFormula` to copy from `column 1`. If you go to the `Filter 1` filter view, you'll note that `column 3` is blank except for an error. This happens after I try to `Sort Z->A` on column 2. In my more complicated use-case, involving a `Vlookup`, after a `Sort` the column disappears entirely (leaving no `#REF!` error). Before sorting in both cases, everything is fine.

How do I make ArrayFormula values persist in filter views after sorting?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution for my usecase, in your case, it could be:

```
=arrayformula(if(row(C:C)=1;"Column 3";A:A))
```

But you'll need to consider the whole columns in your formulas.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYFTW.png)

Comment: This worked for me for some columns but not others.

Comment: This worked for me too, but took me a long time to understand what you meant, so let me try to expand...

You need to set the formula to *first row* of column C, so that it updates the whole column. To make sure that the column has a header which you want, you have the IF - basically if this is first row, show "Column 3" in the cell.

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing that, because your references are normal (relative, not anchored/absolute), the range A2:A10 after sorting down turns into something absurd, like A7:A4, depending on actual sorted values.

Also, if you hover with your mouse on the #REF error, what does it tell you?

Anyway, try using absolute references in your formula:

```
=arrayformula({"Column 3"; A$2:A$10})
```

***Edit***
Fascinating. It's the first time I see this type of error. Taking it at face value, it seems that it's a limitation of Google Spreadsheets - you cannot use ARRAYFORMULAS spanning multiple rows inside sorted filter views, because, like I sort of guessed, it messes up the ARRAYFORMULA's range (as indicated by the fact that the formula is now in C4 instead of C1).

But that gives you also the solution: do not include the cell with the arrayformula in the filter view. Instead of making your filter view's target range A1:C20, make it A1:B20. Then the arrayformula in C1 will be untouched by the filter and will indeed continue to work.
[image]

Comment: Absolute references didn't fix the problem for me. Edited to include the popup error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried A2:A?
If you don't put an ending row, means the end of the column.
It worked for me.

Cheers